# Gps warning messages on Binder threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, gps

I'm running a Gps positioning element from my main `Activity`on a different thread than the UI thread:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
public Handler gpshandler = null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Thread gpsThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {     
            Looper.prepare();
            gpshandler = new Handler();
            gps = new GPSClass(MyActivity.this);
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }, "GPSThread");
    gpsThread.start();
}
...
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    gps.onPause();
    gpshandler.getLooper().quit();
}
```

My GPSClass is as follows:

```
public class GPSClass implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener{
    private double latitute, longitude;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private GpsStatus status;
    private boolean hasGPSFix = false;
    private Location lastLoc;
    private long lastLocTime;
    private boolean started = false;

public GPSClass(Context context) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);

    start();
    started = true;
}

private void start() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);

    if(hasGPSFix || !started) {
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    } else {
        provider = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) ? 
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER : locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    }

    if(provider != null){
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            latitute = 0.0;
            longitude = 0.0;
        }
    }
    computeLocation();
}

public void computeLocation(){
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 100, this);     
}

public void onPause(){
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location == null) return;

    lastLocTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    latitute = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    lastLoc = location;             
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    start();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    start();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { // not a good method, there are some issues with it not being called, don't rely on it!
    if(status != LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE){
        start();
    }
}

public double getLatitute() {
    return latitute;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public String getProvider() {
    return provider;
}

@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
    status = locationManager.getGpsStatus(status);
    switch (event) {
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
        // Do Something 
        break;
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
        // Do Something 
        break;
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
        hasGPSFix  = true;
        // Do Something 
        break;
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
        if (lastLoc != null)
            hasGPSFix = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastLocTime) < 10000;

        if (hasGPSFix) {

// Do something.
        } else { 
            start();
        }

        // Do Something
        break;
    }       
}
}
```

I use the gpshandler to perform the Looper.quit() method and get the locations using the get methods of my gps object.

This method works fine and I'm able get the info I want. However, I sometimes(half of the time) get the following warning messages:

```
Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {41ada040} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler     (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {41ada040} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onGpsStopped(LocationManager.java:1382)
at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:57)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

or

```
Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {41ada040} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler     (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {41ada040} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1382)
at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:57)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

These warnings don't influence the process but I'd like to understand what is happening...
Using DDMS I found that these warnings happen on Binder threads. Does anyone know why this is happening and why it doesn't happen all the time? Thanks

**Edit**

I've dug down a bit and I've realised that when they occur, they can occur on all of the Binders but that they affect only two of them at a time. I'm not familiar with Binders, but could it be that there is a broadcasting of the status? I don't know how to know to which threads the Binders are attached and I've tried debugging, but for some reason I can't reproduce the warnings in debug mode. However, I set a debug Log in the onGpsStatusChanged method which reports the gps status received. Here is the output of the logcat. I've just edited it in order to show on which threads the messages occur.

```
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-12 09:32:18.133: D/gps(GPSThread): got status 4   
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:18.133: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_1):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-12 09:32:19.128: D/gps(GPSThread): got status 4   
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at  android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:19.128: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-12 09:32:20.123: D/gps(GPSThread): got status 4   
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:20.123: W/MessageQueue(Binder_4):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)

12-12 09:32:21.173: D/gps(GPSThread): got status 4   
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:21.173: W/MessageQueue(Binder_2):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:21.178: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

12-12 09:32:22.108: D/gps(GPSThread): got status 4   
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {425536f8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_5):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1) {42602058} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.onSvStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:1406)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.location.IGpsStatusListener$Stub.onTransact(IGpsStatusListener.java:89)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
12-12 09:32:22.113: W/MessageQueue(Binder_3):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you kill the looper, do you call [`.removeGpsStatusListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeGpsStatusListener%28android.location.GpsStatus.Listener%29) somewhere before that happens?

Comment: No I don't, but the warnings appear before I kill the looper, so that doesn't seem to be the problem... But I'll have to check if I have to use removeGpsStatusListener() when the Gps signal is lost. Thanks for the input ;)

Comment: Your error says `GpsStatusListenerTransport` .. `Handler on a dead thread` and `Looper` is the part that defines a `Handler` (it's accepting messages put into it's queue, then calling specified `Handler`). Sounds to me like the status updates try to talk to the looper and find it dead.

Comment: I agree with you, but my gps thread is not dead(checked in DDMS) and I still get the call to the onGPSStatusChanged(int event) method... I've also looked at the [LocationManager](http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/49963_LocationManager.java) source code to see if I could find something, but didn't find anything...

Comment: Is it the same gps thread and most importantly the same `Looper`? (you should be able to see that based on the thread id somewhere)

Comment: @zapl I've edited my question. The gps thread is the same, there's only one according to the DDMS, but I don't know how to check the Looper...

Comment: `Looper.loop()` is an endless loop that receives the messages. It's only stopping if you `.quit()` it. And you will need a new one in that case. `Binder` is Android's [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism. Sensor measurements are done by some system process that's how the measurements are transported into your app process. What those threads should do in the end is to enqueue a message for your `Looper`. You say "I use the gpshandler to perform the Looper.quit()" but I don't see that in the code you posted so I'm trying to figure out if that could be related

Comment: ohh, well I do the `gpshandler.getLooper().quit()` in the `onDestroy()` of my main activity(`MyActivity`). What's bugging me is that it doesn't happen every time! If the `Binder`s can't send the info, how come I do get it?

Comment: Can you add that part to your question? It should not happen if you also remove the GPS listener which has (and keeps!) an internal reference to the then dead `Looper` (it creates a `Handler` which uses [`Looper#myLooper()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#myLooper%28%29) to get the current thread's looper).

Comment: @zapl I think I have an idea of what is happening, but I'll have to try it out to be sure. I'll keep you updated

Comment: @zapl I fixed the warnings, it was more or less related to our discussion and your input set me on the path. Can I vote you up somehow before answering my question?

Comment: I'm glad I could help, that's worth more than reputation (there is also not much you get beyond 10k :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what was really happening, but I have a vague idea... I was adding the GPS listener before having done `Looper.loop()` and before having fully initialised my GPSClass.
Therefore, I'm guessing that sometimes the `LocationProvider` used by the `LocationManager` crashed because my listener class had no yet finished being initialised or because the looper hadn't started.

However, the listener was still added which may explain why I was still getting the updates. I still don't understand why I was getting the warnings on different `Binders` though...
The solution I found was to add the Gps listener to the `LocationManager` in a method triggered by my activity's `onResume()` instead of in the `onCreate` and to do `.removeGpsStatusListener()` when the GPSClass performed the `onPause()`.

Many thanks to you zapl for your input ;)